# Automatic Script Minification and Combination?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, minify

Does anyone know what is being used in this article ([Building an HTML5 App with ASP.NET by Stephen Walther](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2011/01/11/building-an-html5-app-with-asp-net.aspx)) to compress the javascript files?

About 1/2 way down in the blog entry, he says: "All of the custom JavaScript files are combined and minified automatically whenever the application is built with Visual Studio."

However, I've never heard of that being built into Visual Studio.

What is being used to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further investigation, it appears that his sample project included a custom project that uses the `Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.Minifier`.